# Добавлять информацию user profle сразу после регистрации

Tags: python, django

Есть модель UserPorofile он есть у каждого юзера и всегда есть не надо создавать.
логинить юзера после регистра тоже не получается и добавлять поле userprofile.
дает ошибку не найдено совпадении.
как после строки user.save() сделать вход или добавить поле в profile

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='imageusers', verbose_name='Изображение')
    phone = models.TextField()

    teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

admin.py:

```
class UserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Данные пользователя'


class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserInline, )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

view регистрации

```
    @csrf_exempt
    def registeruser(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            login = request.POST.get('username')
            mail = request.POST.get('mail')

            firstname = request.POST.get('firstname')
            lastname = request.POST.get('lastname')

            phone = request.POST.get('phone')
            avatar = request.POST.get('avatar')

            password = request.POST.get('password')
            passwordtwo = request.POST.get('passwordtwo')
            if password != passwordtwo:
                messages.error(request, 'Ծածկաբառերը չեն համընկնում')
            elif User.objects.filter(username=login).exists():
                messages.error(request, 'Նման լոգինով մարդ գոյուտյուն ունի')
            elif login == '' or mail == '' or firstname == '' or lastname == '' or phone == '' or password == '' or passwordtwo == '':
                messages.error(request, 'Լրացրեք ամբողջ տվյալները')
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=login, password=password)
                user.first_name = firstname
                user.last_name = lastname
                user.email = mail
                user.save()
                gdg = User.objects.get(username=user.use

rname)
            gd = UserProfile.objects.get(user=gdg)
            gdg.userprofile.phone = phone
            gdg.userprofile.avatar = avatar
            gdg.userprofile.save()


    return render(request, 'accounts/regform.html')
```

Comment: Расставьте знаки препинания, переформулируйте предложения и опишите подробнее, что значит "не получается". В текущем виде вопрос непонятен.

Comment: ошибка не нашел совпадении может код вообще не правильный?

Comment: а как после этого регистрации делать login?

Comment: С помощью authenticate, что находится в django.contrib.auth

Comment: не получается пышет   строка нельзя вызвать как метод

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил создание профиля и автоматическую авторизацию после этого.

```
    @csrf_exempt
    def registeruser(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            login = request.POST.get('username')
            mail = request.POST.get('mail')

            firstname = request.POST.get('firstname')
            lastname = request.POST.get('lastname')

            phone = request.POST.get('phone')
            avatar = request.POST.get('avatar')

            password = request.POST.get('password')
            passwordtwo = request.POST.get('passwordtwo')
            if password != passwordtwo:
                messages.error(request, 'Ծածկաբառերը չեն համընկնում')
            elif User.objects.filter(username=login).exists():
                messages.error(request, 'Նման լոգինով մարդ գոյուտյուն ունի')
            elif login == '' or mail == '' or firstname == '' or lastname == '' or phone == '' or password == '' or passwordtwo == '':
                messages.error(request, 'Լրացրեք ամբողջ տվյալները')
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=login, password=password)
                user.first_name = firstname
                user.last_name = lastname
                user.email = mail
                user.save()
                UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, phone=phone, avatar=avatar) # создание профиля
                user_login = authenticate(request, username=login, password=password) # проверка логина и пароля
                if user_login is not None:
                    login(request, user_login) # авторизация
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/') # редирект на главную
    return render(request, 'accounts/regform.html')
```

К импортам:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
```

Comment: огромное спасибо